# How can I add score counter on spritekit Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, scoring

I want to make scoring on my game its need to add 3 point every second 
I wrote a code like this

```
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
let scoreLabelName = "scoreLabel"
var count = 0

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    addPlayer()

    scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ScoreLabel")
    scoreLabel.name = scoreLabelName
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 125
    scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
    scoreLabel.text = "\(count)"
    print(size.height)
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height - 300)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
}
```

Comment: You're are on the right track - have you tied to implement any code to make the score increase over time?

Comment: <i> func scoring () {
       var time: TimeInterval
        
        if time > 1.0 {
            count += 3
            time = 0
        }
        
        
    }           </i>        is it true or not

Comment: Put all the code you have related to this function into your question - it's difficult to see it as a comment.

Comment: You can go either with update: method like suggested in a given answer, or by using SKActions.

Answer (score 1):

Remember...In SpriteKit you have the [`update`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519802-update) method which get called regularly and which gives you the `currentTime` :)

So you could:

- add a variable to keep track of "the last time you updated"
- check that against the `currentTime` in `update`
- if the difference > 1...bingo! You update your "last time you updated" value to match `currentTime` and update whatever you'd like to update.

So in your case, something along the lines of:

```
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
let scoreLabelName = "scoreLabel"
var count = 0
var lastUpdateTime: TimeInterval?
```

And then update:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    var delta = TimeInterval()
    if let last = lastUpdateTime {
        delta = currentTime - last
    } else {
        delta = currentTime
    }
    if delta > 1.0 {
        //tick tock, a second has passed, update lastUpdateTime
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime
        count += 3
        scoreLabel.text = "\(count)"
    }
}}
```

Hope that gives you some clues.